# How is current distributed in the cross-section of a wire? Skin effect for motor windings?

Tags: motor, winding, skin-effect

The startup h3x is claiming to have designed 3d printed coils and other innovations increasing the power density of electric motors by a factor of 3.

https://www.h3x.tech/#amcoils

They mention fill factor, so presumably the coil has other materials that are not as conductive. I was just wondering what the electron flow distribution is in a wire, and in a coil. For a motor coil we are talking about relatively low frequency, is there skin effect? There is a lot of adjacent magnetic field, so what is the distribution of current in the cross-section, and are there "dead areas" that can be efficiently removed so the copper is used more efficiently?

Comment: What frequency are we talking about?

Comment: Skin effect is always there once you have AC (even for 0.1Hz). It might not be a concern due to the depth Vs the current but it's there. The windings need insulation and this takes up some space and thus reduces slot fill

Comment: Assuming this motor runs on 60 Hz and uses copper wire for its windings, the skin depth for copper is approximately 0.33 inches.  So unless this motor is wound with really big wire, changing the cross section of its windings is not going to impact how much current they can carry.  So if the 3X improvement in power density is real, they ust be using other techniques to achieve that.  Maybe improving the cooling?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The claim cited is power density for motors and inverters combined. That and the fact that the target market is aircraft propulsion indicated that the frequency is likely higher than 60 Hz. One way to increase motor power density is to operate it at a higher speed, requiring a higher frequency. Since speed is generally proportional to frequency and voltage while torque is proportional to current and  stator-rotor air gap dimensions, increasing speed can be accomplished with much less increase in size than increasing torque. It seems likely that the motors cited are high-speed, high frequency motors. That would make skin effect a bigger issue.

Fill-factor is largely a matter of packing factor, or elimination of air spaces. The cited motors used additive manufacturing AKA 3-D printing techniques to improve fill factor.

Comment: Did you mean "speed is proportional to frequency"?

Comment: @ SteveSh Yes, thank you.